# iReport, use SQL instead HQL query with an hibernate connection

Tags: sql, hibernate, ireport

i'm writing a query that need UNION and hql doesn't support it. So the only workaround is to use standrad SQL query but the problem is i can't use it in iReport if i use hibernate.

There is a way to use sql in iReport with an hibernate connection?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a View. See this: [Hibernate Union alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201023/hibernate-union-alternatives)