# How to do a Union SQL statement in HQL?

Tags: hibernate, grails, hql, grails-controller

I'm trying to create a Union between two tables, using HQL (Hibernate Query Language).  This SQL script works fine on my SQL server:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT linkedin_id) as test, school_name
FROM
(SELECT * FROM alum_education 
 UNION
 SELECT * FROM alum_connection_educations) AS UNIONS where school_name='some string'
```

the problem is, when i try to run it in grails like this:

```
     def countOfEdu = AlumEducation.executeQuery("select count (distinct linkedinId ) as countOfEdu, schoolName as SchoolName from (SELECT * FROM alumEducation UNION SELECT * FROM alumConnectionEducations) AS UNIONS where schoolName='some string'" )
```

i get this error:

```
  org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 83 [select count(distinct linkedinId )  as countOfEdu, schoolName as SchoolName  from (SELECT * FROM alumEducation UNION SELECT * FROM alumConnectionEducations) AS UNIONS where schoolName='Duquesne University']
```

How can I run the above SQL statement in grails?

thanks
jason

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201023/hibernate-union-alternatives

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Unions are not supported by HQL. There is an [issue](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-1050) in Hibernate's JIRA that is open since 2005.

Comment: But is duplicated by "**[HHH-3971](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-3971) Using UNION ALL , INTERSECTION functionality in hibernate**", and it was closed

Comment: The issue HHH-1050 is now closed and says « Support for set operations (UNION, INTERSECT, EXCEPT) was added in Hibernate 6.0. »

Answer (score 1):

I would like to share a way I have found to avoids this situation. The only rule here is to have the same type, in this case a String, corresponding to the type of the return list, you could add as many tables as you want:

```
public List<String> findByCPForCNPJ(String query){
TypedQuery<String> ccpf = manager.createQuery("select cpf from PessoaFisica where cpf like :pCpf", String.class);
ccpf.setParameter("pCpf", "%" + query + "%");
List<String> lista1 = ccpf.getResultList();

TypedQuery<String> ccnpj = manager.createQuery("select cnpj from PessoaJuridica where cnpj like :pCnpj", String.class);
ccnpj.setParameter("pCnpj", "%" + query + "%");

lista1.addAll(ccnpj.getResultList());
return lista1;
}
```

I used a method in JAVA for this solution.
I hope I have contributed a bit, good luck to all...

Answer (score 1):

> Support for set operations (UNION, INTERSECT, EXCEPT) was added in Hibernate 6.0.

See the [issue](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-1050?focusedCommentId=107954) linked by Andrey Adamovich

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the real problem is that subqueries are not supported in FROM clause in EJBQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use native query to get result set.