# How to write HQL query for the following SQL Query?

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, hql

This is a query to fetch data from two tables

> blogs

and

> askquestions

HQL query For following SQL query:

```
select title , date from (select blog_title as title ,created_date as date from  blog  union select ask_question as title , created_on as date from askquestions ) as aa order by date desc
```

Thanks in advance for any answers or suggestions!!!

Answer (score 0):

Unions are not supported by hibernate, see [How to do a Union SQL statement in HQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182433/how-to-do-a-union-sql-statement-in-hql)

For an alternative see [Hibernate Union alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201023/hibernate-union-alternatives)

Comment: Hi StephaneM thanks alot!!can you just tell me how to write a HQL method in DAo implementation???thanks in advance..