# HQL Error in Named Query

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I'm getting Hibernate's message that I have an "Error in named query".

Below is the HQL statement I'm trying to execute.

```
select sum(subtotal)
from (
      select sum(coalesce(sum(t2.amount), 0) - coalesce(sum(t3.amount), 0)) subtotal
      from submission t1
      left join t1.bills t2
      left join t1.payments t3
      where t1.id = 10
      group by t1.id

      union

      select sum(coalesce(sum(t2.amount), 0) - coalesce(sum(t3.amount), 0)) subtotal
      from submission t1
      left join t1.otherBills t2
      left join t1.payments t3
      where t1.id = 10
      group by t1.id
) a1
```

I think the problem might be related to the `sum` function in the outer query or the `union` operator but I haven't been able to narrow it down.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use a subquery after *`From`* clause in HQL. My suggestion is that you can use *`native query`*. For more detail you should look at following link :-
[Hibernate Query Limitation](http://hedleyproctor.com/2014/08/hibernate-query-limitations-and-correlated-sub-queries/)

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate [does not support `union`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182433/how-to-do-a-union-sql-statement-in-hql).

A feature request for that is open for a decade.