# Hibernate/JPA: Is it possible to retrieve heterogeneous entities in a single query?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, persistence

I have 2 entities: EntityA and EntityB.

They are unrelated, and I cannot put them in a Inheritance tree for some restrictions out of the scope of this question.

But I need to get in the same JPQL or HQL query a mixed List containing all the instances of both entities. Is this possible with JPA or even Hibernate directly?

I need somethign like this:

```
FROM EntityA WHERE fieldA=1
UNION
FROM EntityB WHERE fieldB="aa"
```

Any hint?

Comment: The easy way is to make both queries and concatenate both lists in a `List<Object>`.

Comment: Thanks, but as I comment, I am forced to do both in 1 query because I am using pagination, and i cannot paginate independent querys.

Comment: @edutesoy: If you use HQL for that pagination will anyway won't work: see [Hibernate reference](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-polymorphism).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I finally figured it out.

It is enought to make the entities implement a common interface (it is not even needed to declare this interface on Hibernate).

Then, a query like this can be done:

```
FROM my.package.CommonInterface obj
WHERE obj IN (FROM EntityA WHERE fieldA=1) OR
      obj IN (FROM EntityB WHERE fieldB='a')
```

This way, you retrieve a `List<CommonInterface>`.

Problem solved.

Comment: I am interested in the same topic. At the moment I use two queries (two cursors) which return `Iterator` via `criteria.scroll()` and then joining two iterators via `IteratorUtils.chainedIterator()`. I wonder, how Hibernate decides, which object to create from result of the query? And what is the SQL query, generated by HQL you've provided?

Comment: For your first question, Hibernate returns instances of CommonInterface, some of them will be instances of EntityA and someothers of EntityB. For your second question i have no idea about the SQL generated (and it doesn't worry me at this point).

Comment: I had a quick look at the generated SQL. It is not optiomal, as Hibernate generates 2 queries: `SELECT EntityA.* WHERE id IN (SELECT EntityA.id ... WHERE fieldA=1) OR id IN (SELECT EntityB.id ... WHERE fieldB='a')` and `SELECT EntityB.* WHERE id IN (SELECT EntityB.id ... WHERE fieldB='a') OR id IN (SELECT EntityA.id ... WHERE fieldA=1)`. Clearly, the 2nd subselect in each query is wrong (at least in my case). There is not so much information in [Hibernate docu](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-polymorphism) concerning this :(

Comment: After looking around I've come to the conclusion, that optimal SQL possible only in case when both `EntityA` and `EntityB` have the same mapped property `fieldX` (which very probably has a getter declared in common interface: `CommonInterface.getFieldX`). Then the query `FROM my.package.CommonInterface obj WHERE obj.fieldX = 1` will result 2 SQL queries, but they will be optimal.

Comment: Yes, you are right, 2 queries are performed for each one of the entities, and i would say that this behavior of Hibernate is totally WRONG!! I would even say that it is a BUG, because if you try, for example, to SORT the results of the query, it simply doesn't work, it just applies the ORDER BY to each one of the SQL queries independently, instead of aplying it to the whole collection. A complete screwup, i would like to think of a workaround, because for me is a problem right now.

Comment: I opened a new question for this matter here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482129/how-can-i-work-around-this-hibernate-limitation

Comment: It's not a bug, you have requested to read from `CommonInterface` which results into two entities and thus two SQL requests. Then the `WHERE` condition (with problematic `OR`) is then applied for each SQL. That is by design. Look at @UdoFholl answer: he proposes a working solution.

Comment: I would say that it is a bug, because Hibernate has all the information to construct the proper SQL through a UNION instead of launching independent queries. It is doable but it is just not implemented that way in Hibernate... The fact is that i am launching a HQL query with a well defined semmantics, and Hibernate is not fulfilling these semmantics but other (due to the way it translates from HQL to SQL).

Comment: I was wrong, it is not posible with UNION because the different types, but Hibernate should maintain the semantics of the HQL language even if it needs to do processing in memory...

Answer (score 2):

Best thing is to performs two queries.

But if you must:

You can create a `POJO` to retrieve them:

```
class EntityAandEntityB {
    EntityA a;
    EntityB b;
    long idA;
    long idB;
    int fieldA;
    String fieldB;

    public EntityAandEntityB(long idA, long IdB, int fieldA, String fieldB) {
       this.a = new EntityA(idA, fieldA);
       this.b = new EntityB(idB, fieldB);
    }
}
```

Then your query would be:

```
select new package.EntityAandEntityB(a.idA, a.fieldA, b.idB, b.fieldB) from ( 
    (select idA, fieldA from EntityA) a
UNION
    (select idB, fieldB from EntityB) b)
```

This is dirty and you probably must to look carefully the syntax.

Regards.

Comment: Could you mentioned the SQL query, which is generated by Hibernate from HQL you've provided?

Comment: Thanks for this solution: I've learned a lot when reading corresponding [Hibernate chapter](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-select). Is it possible to `scroll()` the resulting query? I guess, not...