# How can I work-around this Hibernate Limitation?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, orm

I have 3 entities in a Hierarchy like this:

```
         MyInterface
              |
      -----------------
      |               |
   Entity1          Entity2
```

The MyInterface is NOT mapped in Hibernate (because I am using [implicit polymorphism strategy](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html#inheritance-tableperconcreate-polymorphism) to map this inheritance)

And, in fact, if I launch a query like this one:

```
"FROM MyInterface"
```

It works just fine (because it retrieves all the instances of Entity1 and all the instances of Entity2, puts them together, and returns a `List<MyInterface>`).

If we look at the SQL generated by Hibernate, it is launching 2 independent SQL queries to first retrieve the Entity1 instances an another one to retrieve Entity2 instances, but I am fine with this.

The BIG problem comes when you try to do something like this:

```
"FROM MyInterface ORDER BY someField"
```

Because it is applying the ORDER BY to the first SQL query and then the same ORDER BY to the second SQL query, instead of apply them to the **WHOLE query** (I know this because I can see the native SQL queries launched by Hibernate).

This is clearly a missbehaviour of Hibernate.

How can I work around this to force Hibernate to apply the ORDER BY to the whole query? (I cannot do it in memory because later I will have to add pagination also).

Comment: Can you provide the mappings you are using?

Comment: I am mapping the Entities as independent entities (nothing special), and I am just making them implementors of MyInterface in Java level (not in Hibernate). This is a hard simplification so i have not got the mapping XML of the entities, but the mapping is the same as any other regular entity, but just implementing a common MyInterface, nothing else.

Comment: Well, try to write an SQL querry that selects from two different tables and order by a common field. IMHO that is impossible, hence hibernate can't do it either.

Comment: UNION gives you some room. Anyway, Hibernate defines a SEMANTICS for the HQL meaning, and it is not fulfilling these semantics due to a limitation of the underlying technology. IMHO Hibernate should overcome this limitation using SQL if possible, of doing the calculations in memory to maintain the semantics of the language.

Comment: I think it would be cheap to do merge on `someField` in hibernate, when it builds the collection.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the problem is that Hibernate has to create those 2 SQL queries because you have to read from 2 tables.

I'm not sure if reading from 2 tables and ordering by 2 columns (one from each table) in one query is possible in plain SQL (means no vendor specific extensions), and if not, Hibernate would have to do the ordering in memory anyways.

What you could do when applying paging is: read the ids and the values you want to sort by only (not the entire entity), then sort in memory and read the entire entity for all ids contained in the page. For paging to be consistent you might have to store the results of that initial query (id + order criteria) anyways.

Answer (score 1):

The way you are thinking cannot be mapped to SQL as is. Suppose you have `Entity1` with fields `field1A`, `field1B` ... and `Entity2` with fields `field2A`, `field2B`, ... Now you want the following query to be executed:

```
SELECT Entity1.* FROM Entity1
UNION
SELECT Entity2.* FROM Entity2
ORDER BY CommonField
```

which is not possible in SQL world, as entities have different number of fields and different field types.

So you need to think about extracting common fields into separate table `CommonEntity`, converting your interface into standalone entity with with one-to-one mapping to `Entity1` & `Entity2` (see [Table per subclass](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html#inheritance-tablepersubclass)). Then SQL will look like:

```
SELECT * from CommonEntity LEFT OUTER JOIN Entity1 ON Entity1.refId = CommonEntity.id LEFT OUTER JOIN Entity2 ON Entity2.refId = CommonEntity.id
ORDER BY CommonField
```

Or you can create a view over your tables and introduce an artificial discriminator (discriminator is something which will "distinguish" IDs from different tables, which caused a problem in [your solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322526/hibernate-jpa-is-it-possible-to-retrieve-heterogeneous-entities-in-a-single-quer/7334243#7334243)) and then map an entity to this view (so we get [Table per class hierarchy](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html#inheritance-tableperclass)):

```
CREATE VIEW EntityAandEntityB AS
SELECT 'A' as discriminator, Entity1.ID, CommonField1, ... CommonFieldZ, Entity1.field1A, ... Entity1.field1N, NULL, NULL,                          ... NULL(M)
FROM Entity1
UNION
SELECT 'B' as discriminator, Entity2.ID, CommonField1, ... CommonFieldZ, NULL, NULL,                          ... NULL(N), Entity2.field2A, ... Entity2.field2M
FROM Entity2
ORDER BY CommonField1, ...
```

Other alternatives (e.g. mentioned by [@UdoFholl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322526/hibernate-jpa-is-it-possible-to-retrieve-heterogeneous-entities-in-a-single-quer/7322738#7322738) which is also kind of "outer join" for `EntityAandEntityB`) will result 2 SQLs and thus there is no way to order the "whole" query, and [scrolling is not possible](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-polymorphism).

Comment: This sounds good and is a creative solution, but i would lose the polimorfism which i need because both Entity1 and Entity2 have custom data and behaviour, i need the list to contain polimorfic instances of Entity1 and Entity2...

Comment: @edutesoy: I fully understand your goal, as I am also wondering, how to achieve this and very very surprised to see the "solution" (even wrong). But look at the problem from different perspective: (1) SQL does not guarantee the order of lines (2) when Hibernate sees the row `X`, how it can decide which entity to create? To solve this it needs a discriminator or super-entity.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate will do this for you if you use the following.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class AbstractEntity implements MyInterface {
    private int someField;
}
```

Then have your subclasses that do this

```
@Entity
@Table(name="entity_1")
public class EntityOne extends AbstractEntity {
    private int someOtherField;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="entity_2")
public class EntityTwo extends AbstractEntity {
    private int anotherSomeOtherField;
}
```

You should then be able to write a query like this to get a single union SQL query with the DB doing the ordering.

```
FROM AbstractEntity ORDER BY someField
```

Comment: Do I need an extra physical table to do this? because I cannot change the underlying tables so i could not add this new table.

Comment: No, This will mapped the two concrete entities to their own tables. Both tables will need the someField column and that column will need to be of the same type in both tables. The other columns can be entity specific.

Comment: My problem with this is that to for this kind of mapping Inheritance i would need to do this http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html#inheritance-tableperconcrete and it forces me to have the same field name of the table for the KEY of the entity. And my Table model is locked, and the KEY of the tables are the same type, but not the same name... i cannot use this kind of mapping. This is a good proposal though.

Comment: Are you sure you can't use it? I think you can have the id in each subclass mapping to a different field. The ID generation is the limitation. See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#d0e1168 for more details. Worth a try.

Comment: Yes, I already tried and you cannot specify an ID inside the subclass element... sadly.

Comment: Too bad. Then it looks like you might have to merge and sort the data form the separate queries. This sort of thing happens when using some legacy systems. :-(