# Is there any way to merge columns from multiple table to single list?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have gathered records from 3 different tables using common key i.e common column for three tables and stored in 3 lists per,deg,deg.

```
Query query2 = s.createQuery("from StuPersonal where FRID = :dd");
query2.setParameter("dd",jp.getFRID());
per=query2.list();

Query query3 = s.createQuery("from StuDegree where FRID = :dd");
query2.setParameter("dd",jp.getFRID());
deg=query3.list();

Query query4 = s.createQuery("select city from StuWorkPref where FRID = :dd");
query2.setParameter("dd",jp.getFRID());
swf=query4.list();
```

Now, I need to combine the fields(columns) in the 3 list into a single list and i need to give output to the user...Is there any way? Please advice..

I have declared list as

```
List<StuPersonal> per=new ArrayList();
List<StuDegree> deg=new ArrayList();
List<StuWorkPref> swp=new ArrayList();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322526/hibernate-jpa-is-it-possible-to-retrieve-heterogeneous-entities-in-a-single-que/7322738#7322738

Comment: Is all list are same size?

Comment: Common Column means? Why not join ?

Comment: using Hibernate. join is only possible if there is any relation between the table. If there is no relation then join is not possible

Comment: I have joined the table using one to many concept..i.e FRID will be there in every table..

Answer (score 2):

You can concatenate two Arraylists using the addAll method. It adds all the members of the parametrized list to the invoking list.
In your case, you will need a superclass of the three classes you mentioned.

```
List<Superclass> finalList=new ArrayList();
finalList.addAll(per);
finalList.addAll(deg);
finalList.addAll(swp);
```

To rephrase, you can store derived class objects in an ArrayList of the Base class. The design becomes cleaner using this approach as you can have generic methods in your Superclass and let the derived classes reuse them. Later, you can have over-ridden methods for the derived classes for doing class-specific operations on the individual objects.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
List<Object[]> resList=new ArrayList<>();

int maxSize=/*Get the maximum size of three list*/

 for(int i=0;i<maxSize;i++){
    Object[] obj=new Object[3];
    obj[0]=peg.get(i);
    obj[1]=deg.get(i);
    obj[2]=swf.get(i);

    resList.add(obj);
 }
```

Comment: peg, deg, swf are the list of object and get() will return an object so can't be stored in String.

Comment: @AshishAggarwal, I knew that after edit the question.