# How to use subquery into "from" clause in hibernate?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, subquery, hql

I have three tables: `class`, `student`, and `teacher`

```
table class
{
    class_id(PK)
}

table student
{
    student_id(PK)
    class_id(PK+FK)
}

table teacher
{
    teacher_id(PK)
    class_id(PK+FK)
}
```

I have a query in SQL, which works fine.

```
SELECT data.class_id, count(data.class_id) AS count
FROM ((SELECT class_id FROM student)
        union all
        (SELECT class_id FROM teacher)) AS data
GROUP BY data.user_id
ORDER BY count desc
```

The query contains sub query in the **from clause** and **union operation**.
I unable to convert it to the HQL.

please give me the efficient HQL query from the above SQL query.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately [HQL does not support UNION queries](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-1050). Two alternative strategies to solve your problem are:

- Mapping a [Pojo to a a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201023/hibernate-union-alternatives)
- Or [Inheritance mapping](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch10.html). Particularly [Table per concrete class](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch10.html#inheritance-tableperconcrete) strategy with an abstract `Person` superclass inherited both by `Student` and `Teacher` seems to fit your problem well:

  ```
  select p.id, count(c)
  from Person p join p.classes c
  group by p.id
  order by count(c) desc
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the documentation links. Re-reading those sections was worth it.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot place a subquery at the `from` clause in HQL. Only `select` or `where` clauses.