# HQL merge two typedqueries

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hql

I have written two hibernate queries:

1. TypedQuery q = em.createQuery("SELECT user.id FROM TableOne AS user WHERE ...", Long.class);
2. TypedQuery q = em.createQuery("SELECT link.user_id FROM TableTwo AS link WHERE ...", Long.class);

Now, how do I merge these two queries? My return type has to be TypedQuery

Comment: The SQL equivalent would be a Union statement right? JPQL doesn't support such, although some JPA provider does. Why the queries need to be merged into one TypedQuery? Can't you execute both and return a Set<Long> wrapping into another method?

Comment: How can I use SQL equivalent to return TypedQuery? Will following work? TypedQuery q = em.createQuery("SELECT user.id FROM TableOne AS user WHERE ... UNION SELECT link.user_id FROM TableTwo AS link WHERE ...", Long.class);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completely copying answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/3940445/929701:

You could use id in (select id from ...) or id in (select id from ...)

e.g. instead of non-working

```
from Person p where p.name="Joe"
union
from Person p join p.children c where c.name="Joe"
```

you could do

```
from Person p 
  where p.id in (select p1.id from Person p1 where p1.name="Joe") 
    or p.id in (select p2.id from Person p2 join p2.children c where c.name="Joe");
```

At least using MySQL, you will run into performance problems with the later though. It's sometimes easier to do a poor man's join on two queries instead:

```java
// use set for uniqueness
Set<Person> people = new HashSet<Person>((List<Person>) query1.list());
people.addAll((List<Person>) query2.list());
return new ArrayList<Person>(people);
```

It's often better to do two simple queries than one complex one.

Answer (score 0):

the UNION statement not work on Hibernate.

So you can:

Execute first query and put in a list;

Execute second query and put in a list;

Put the result of first and second list in a unique list.

If you want to delete the duplicated value, you must do programmatically.