# HQL not working "in" with multiple values

Tags: java, hibernate

I have hibernate which goes something like this.

```
String queryString = "from MFunction as mFunction where mFunction.functionKey in " 
            + "((select mRole.enterprise  from MRole as mRole where mRole.roleKey=:role), " 
            + "(select mRole2.project from MRole as mRole2 where mRole2.roleKey=:role ), " 
            + "(select mRole3.technology  from MRole  as mRole3 where mRole3.roleKey=:role ))";
```

But the hibernate query takes in only the first value.

```
Hibernate: select mfunction0_.FunctionKey as Function1_73_, mfunction0_.`Add` as Add2_73_, mfunction0_.`Audit` as Audit3_73_, mfunction0_.ClientKey as ClientKey73_, mfunction0_.CreatedBy as CreatedBy73_, mfunction0_.CreatedTs as CreatedTs73_, mfunction0_.`Delete` as Delete7_73_, mfunction0_.`Edit` as Edit8_73_, mfunction0_.`Financial` as Financial9_73_, mfunction0_.FunctionName as Functio10_73_, mfunction0_.`General` as General11_73_, mfunction0_.Level as Level73_, mfunction0_.LevelKey as LevelKey73_, mfunction0_.LogicalDeleteTms as Logical14_73_, mfunction0_.UpdatedBy as UpdatedBy73_, mfunction0_.UpdatedTs as UpdatedTs73_, mfunction0_.`View` as View17_73_ from appanalytixdb.M_Function mfunction0_ where mfunction0_.FunctionKey in (select mrole1_.Enterprise from appanalytixdb.M_Role mrole1_ where mrole1_.RoleKey=?)
```

Hibernate version: 4.1.8.Final

Comment: Comma is inside quotes. Below query will work.

    String queryString = "from MFunction as mFunction where mFunction.functionKey in " 
            + "((select mRole.enterprise  from MRole as mRole where mRole.roleKey=:role) ", 
            + "(select mRole2.project from MRole as mRole2 where mRole2.roleKey=:role ) ", 
            + "(select mRole3.technology  from MRole  as mRole3 where mRole3.roleKey=:role ))";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you created a list of lists, and you should create a single list of functionkeys.

I see only 2 options:

1. Change one 'in' to 3 statements connected with or.

String queryString = "from MFunction as mFunction where mFunction.functionKey in (select mRole.enterprise  from MRole as mRole where mRole.roleKey=:role) or mFunction.functionKey in (select mRole2.project from MRole as mRole2 where mRole2.roleKey=:role ) or mFunction.functionKey in (select mRole3.technology  from MRole  as mRole3 where mRole3.roleKey=:role )";

2. Best solution would be to preselect all projects,technologies,enterprise and union them together (to avoid duplicates). But hibernate does not yet support union, according to this post [Hibernate Union alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201023/hibernate-union-alternatives).
   If you have not so many entries in your tables, I would create a view, and used my query on it. Views can be quite cheap and easy to use in this scenarios.