# Join different tables determined by a control filed

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

There are three tables A and B1 and B2:

```
A(id, b_id, control)
B1(id, other)
B2(id, other)

If control = 1, b_id in A is mapping to table B1;
If control = 2, b_id in A is mapping to table B2.
```

These three classes is like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class A {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    private B b;

    @Column(name = "control")
    private Integer control;
} 

@Entity
@Table(name = "B1")
public class B1 {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "other")
    private Integer other;
}
```

Class B2 is almost same with B1.

I need get different object B from table B1 or B2 determined by field `control` in class A. Is it possible to make it with hibernate annotation?

Appreciated for any advice.

Comment: `A join B1 on (cotrol = 1...) UNION A join B2 ON(control = 2..)`

Comment: Great, thanks @sagi , so I can make it with HQL at least.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing out the way one table refers to another in SQL. What I mean is by the way you have defined your tables there are no foreign keys and no [referential integrity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity) secured. I would strongly recommend you reconsidering your implementation and add the respective foreign keys in your A table.

Anyway, if you want to continue like this, you should check out the UNION statement in SQL.

```
SELECT A.id, B1.others 
FROM A 
INNER JOIN B1 
ON A.control = 1 AND A.b_id= B1.id
UNION
SELECT A.id, B2.others 
FROM A 
INNER JOIN B2 
ON A.control = 2 AND A.b_id= B2.id
```

Now I have noticed that there is a problem in hql with union statement (not supported I think?) but there are possible other [implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201023/hibernate-union-alternatives).

Also notice that you have to select the same columns in order to union the two subqueries.