# Merging multiple SELECT statements using Hibernate Criteria

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have an SQL query that I would like to rewrite using Hibernate Criteria.

Consider the following simplified version:

```
SELECT * FROM (
          SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY records.created DESC, records.created DESC
          ) AS RowNum, * FROM (
            SELECT a.id AS id
            FROM EntityA a
            UNION 
            SELECT b.id AS id
            FROM EntityB b
          ) AS records
) AS result
```

I approached this by splitting up the query into different parts.

I have written two seperate criterias for each of the two nested SELECTS and merged the resulting two Lists into a SET [as advised here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201023/hibernate-union-alternatives). So that covers:

```
SELECT a.id AS id
FROM EntityA a
UNION 
SELECT b.id AS id
FROM EntityB b
```

Now I would like to create the surrounding query by queryin the resulting SET.

**Questions**

- Can I query the resultset using Criterias?
- If this is not possible, am I approaching this wrong and should I be looking to implement one large Criteria instead of trying to merge multiple smaller ones?

I'm having a little trouble explaining so don't hesitate in asking for more info if needed.

Comment: why not using a nativeQuery ?

Comment: @jpprade Because the actual query is much larger. It's unreadable and hard to maintain