# HQL/SQL - how to group by if there is two column (with different name) as single for grouping

Tags: sql, oracle, hql

i have following problem, example (my tables, and wrong HQL):

```
SELECT to_char(student.dateInserted, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), count(student.dateInserted)
FROM STUDENTS student
INNER JOIN TEACHERS teacher ON (student.teacher_id == teacher.id)
WHERE (student.age > 20 AND student.dateInserted < SYSDATE)
OR (student.age < 20 AND student.dateUpdated  > SYSDATE-2)
GROUP BY to_char(student.dateInserted, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
ORDER BY to_char(student.dateInserted, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

I would like to have output like this table.

```
+--------------------+
|    DATE    | COUNT |
+------------+-------+
| 2018-01-24 | 77    | -- count dateInserted and Updated together
| 2018-01-23 | 16    | -- the same thing
| 2018-01-22 | 22    | -- just dateInserted
|    etc.    | etc.  |
+------------+-------+
```

**Question is: How to that in HQL? And how to that in SQL?**
In HQL I tried CASEs, but without succes.
In SQL I tried outer SELECT and UNION ALL inside, but also without succes.

```
-- SQL attempt (dont mention hql look):
-- And there is problem with first two grouped rows which is not together (2018-01-24 | 27 dateInsered) and (2018_01_24 | 50 dateUpdated)
SELECT datee, summ FROM
(
SELECT to_char(student.dateInserted, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as datee, count(student.dateInserted) as summ
FROM STUDENTS student
INNER JOIN TEACHERS teacher ON (student.teacher_id == teacher.id)
WHERE (student.age > 20 AND student.dateInserted < SYSDATE)
UNION ALL
SELECT to_char(student.dateUpdated, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as datee, count(student.dateUpdated) as summ
FROM STUDENTS student
INNER JOIN TEACHERS teacher ON (student.teacher_id == teacher.id)
WHERE (student.age < 20 AND student.dateUpdated  > SYSDATE-2)
)
GROUP BY datee
ORDER BY datee;
```

Any help appreciated. Please dont mention typos in code and that example doesnt have much sense :) know ... thanks

Comment: What does "without success" mean? Were there errors? If so, what were they? If not, what results did you get, and how did they differ from what you expected? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see what `teacher` has to do with this.  I think this does what you want:

```
SELECT yyyymmdd, SUM(num_inserted) as num_inserted,
       SUM(num_updated) as num_updated,
       SUM(num_inserted + num_updated) as both
FROM ((SELECT TO_CHAR(s.dateInserted, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as yyyymmdd, COUNT(*) as num_inserted, 0 as num_updated
       FROM STUDENTS s
       WHERE (s.age > 20 AND s.dateInserted < SYSDATE) OR
             (s.age < 20 AND s.dateUpdated  > SYSDATE - 2)
       GROUP BY TO_CHAR(s.dateInserted, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT TO_CHAR(s.dateUpdated, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 0, COUNT(*) as num_updated
       FROM STUDENTS s
       WHERE (s.age > 20 AND s.dateInserted < SYSDATE) OR
             (s.age < 20 AND s.dateUpdated  > SYSDATE - 2)
       GROUP BY TO_CHAR(s.dateUpdated, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
      )
     ) s
GROUP BY yyyymmdd
ORDER BY yyyymmdd;
```

Comment: Yes, thats it, group by inside, i thought it is not neccessary. Yes, your right, teacher is not part of problem.
But please edit your WHERE condition, cant have OR a grouping by half of that. In that way my SQL was correct.

Comment: Hmm, but this works only as SQL, HQL doesnt support UNION, so this topis still unresolved.

Comment: @MmM... . . . Oracle does.

Comment: Yes, Oracle does - but hql messes up that - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201023/hibernate-union-alternatives