# Concat 2 filtered results

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have NH query

```
result = Session.Query<s>()
.Include(s => s.a)
.Include(x => x.b)
.Include(x => x.c);
```

and I have two filtered results

```
IQueryable<s> r1 = result.Where(x => x.c.Any(a => a.Id == "value"));
IQueryable<s> r2 = result.Where(x => x.d.Any(a => a.Id == "other"));
```

And I want to have

```
IQueryable<s> r1.Union(r2)
```

Or

```
IQueryable<s> r1.Concat(r2).Distinct()
```

So far everything ok, code compile and run, but in run time I got error:

> The ConcatResultOperator result operator is not current supported

How to concat this two results without lose NHibernate query context.
I know I can cast to list and concat lists but I want still `IQuerable`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

base on [[NH-2710] Support Unions on HQL - NHibernate JIRA](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2710?jql=text%20~%20%22union%22%20order%20by%20created%20DESC)

- it's not supported yet
- you can up-vote the feature request

[image]

more :

- [[NH-2710] Support Unions on HQL - NHibernate JIRA](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2710?jql=text%20~%20%22union%22%20order%20by%20created%20DESC)
- [[HHH-1050] HQL Unions - Hibernate JIRA](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-1050)
- [[HHH-6672] Remove UNION support from 5.x grammars - Hibernate JIRA](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6672)
- [java - Hibernate Union alternatives - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201023/hibernate-union-alternatives)

Comment: Note that relevant issues are now at Github: https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/issues/937 and https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/issues/867