# Use of Union in hibernate HQL query for pagination

Tags: java, hibernate, union

Need usage of Union in hibernate.

I am trying to include 2 different tables with same columns (used for various purpose) in 1 single paginated list.

When I wrote below union query in hibernate

"SELECT * From (
From com.Class1
Union
From com.Class2
) obj order by obj.code"

givers me error saying "Invalid character at col 15"

Need solution for the same

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate Union alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201023/hibernate-union-alternatives)

Comment: Thank you. That means no direct support for Union in Hibernate